# Box2dWeb bodies not colliding

Tags: node.js, box2dweb

I've implemented Box2dWeb into a Node.js server and everything works fine apart from collisions. When there are 2 players connected their bodies don't collide - just go through each other. Here's the player body creation code:

```
//World creation
var world = new b2World(new b2Vec2(0, 0));
//Body+Fixture creation
var bodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
bodyDef.position.x = 100;
bodyDef.position.y = 100;
bodyDef.linearDamping = 5;
bodyDef.angularDamping = 1;

var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef();
fixDef.density = 0.001;
fixDef.friction = 1;
fixDef.restitution = 1;
fixDef.shape = new b2CircleShape;
fixDef.shape.SetRadius(8);

var body = world.CreateBody(bodyDef);
body.CreateFixture(fixDef);
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

EDIT: I've added this code:

```
var listener = new Box2D.Dynamics.b2ContactListener;
listener.BeginContact = function(contact) {
    console.log(contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().GetUserData());
}
world.SetContactListener(listener);
```

and once the bodies collide, I get "null" in the console.

Comment: Hey glad to see you are going ahead with Box2dWeb ;) how are you drawing the bodies on the screen?

Comment: Currently I'm only drawing the bodies on the client by getting the body.GetPosition().

Comment: Could it be an issue with the scale? You need to make sure that when you draw the objects that you are using the correct scale value.

Comment: I just updated the code to the values that I'm using.

Comment: Is there any way you can get an example on jsFiddle? I would say to play around with the figures a little. Maybe make the density=100. You are using 1 world yes?

Comment: I'll try. Yep, 1 world. I don't know if I had to set anything to make the bodies collide, maybe I missed something?

Comment: OK, this is awesome, some progress. I won't be able to run it on jsfiddle, because I'm using Node.js. Anyways, I've changed from "var Box2D = require('../box2d.js')" to "var Box2D = require('../Box2D') and now, on collision I get this error: "Cannot read property 'm_p' of null" Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, that was simple, just as I expected it would be. I changed the code from:

```
this.world.Step(deltaTime);
```

to

```
this.world.Step(deltaTime, 10, 10);
```